# Сгенерировать уникальный uid

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

У нас в конторке есть внутренний ресурс, работающий на django.

Я сделал модель для ведения заявок с генерацией уникального uid для каждой заявки, но заметил такую проблему: создавая несколько заявок, они все были созданы с одним uid. В моделе указано такое вот поле:

```
uuid = models.SmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Уникальный номер заявки', default=random_number())
```

а функция выглядит так:

```
def random_number():
    import random
    rand = random.randrange(1000, 10001, 1)
    return rand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно передать в default вызываемый объект, т.е. функцию.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#default

> The default value for the field. This can be a value or a callable object. If callable it will be called every time a new object is created.

Будет иметь такой вид

```
def random_number():
    import random
    rand = random.randrange(1000, 10001, 1)
    return rand

uuid = models.SmallIntegerField(verbose_name='...', default=random_number)
```

Но вообще ваш вариант чреват пересечениями айди, надо дополнительно позаботиться об уникальности.

Comment: Хм, точно, сразу и не подумал конечно.

Answer (score 0):

```
uuid = models.SmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Уникальный номер заявки', default=random_number())
```

В этом коде uuid присваивается новый экземпляр `models.SmallIntegerField`, которому в конструктор передается значение вызова `random_number()`, т.е. с тем же успехом можно было сделать так:

```
random_number_ = random_number()
uuid = models.SmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Уникальный номер заявки', default=_random_number)
```

Другими словами, в конструктор попадает уже вычисленное значение.

Для создания по-настоящему уникального значения лучше использовать настоящий uuid.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне нужно всего лишь чисел 4-5

Comment: Ну а почему не использовать настоящий `pk` из Джанги? Она сама позаботится об уникальности?

Comment: Начальству хочется так ;)

Comment: Тогда, наверно, проще метод `save` переписать, в нём цикл: генерация случайного числа, проверка на наличие такого в базе, если нет, то присвоение его полю `uuid` и выход из цикла

Answer (score 0):

[uuid](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html) имеет вполне определённый смысл как описано в [RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122). Вместо этого, чтобы сгенерировать уникальное id, как правило используют:

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Если всё таки хочется именно случайный [UUID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID), то:

```
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

Нужно обратить внимание, что передаётся функция uuid4 (без скобок, а не её значение (вызов функции использует скобки в Питоне). Например:

- `default=random_number()`: со скобками, передаётся результат вызова функции `random_number`
- `default=random_number`: без скобок, передаётся сама функция `random_number`

то есть следует использовать `default=uuid.uuid4` вместо `default=uuid.uuid4()`.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснения.